# Finding and removing pull up resistor

Tags: resistors

I'm trying to figure out if the following board has a pull up resistor and if it does how to remove it. It's a SGP41 sensor.

[image]

Comment: ThaNerd - Hi, I assume you mean it's the I2C pull-up resistors you want to remove. I also assume you are not running your host I2C bus at the 1.8V of that sensor and therefore still need level-translation on the I2C bus. If so, your question looks to be effectively a duplicate of one I answered some years ago, on a similar breakout board (different sensor, same I2C level-translation design). See [here](/q/369801/101852). The OP improved on my answer and posted their own. With a better photo of your board, someone could confirm if your solution would be an exact duplicate of answers there.

Comment: (cont'd) As you are new here, please see the site [tour] & [help]. I expect the downvotes on your question are due to it being unclear (i.e. no mention of I2C, why you want to remove a pull-up resistor, and why you mention resistor rather than resistors plural). If you [edit] your question to clarify & improve it, that can only help reduce the concerns from other site members. Thanks.

Comment: You can read the manual, measure or reverse-engineer it. What have you done to figure out if it has pull-ups?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a copy of the Adafruit SGP41 board. It has two level shifters so 10k || 10k effectively on each of SCL and SDA, on either side of each transistor in a dual BSS138.

If you remove the four resistor network it will not work.